# The Riesz Representation Theorem for the Dual of $L^p(E)$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $E$ be a measurable set, $1\leq p<\infty$, and $q$ the conjugate of $p$. For each $g\in L^q(E)$, define the bounded linear functional $T_g$ on $L^p(E)$ by
> \begin{align*}
> T_g(f):= \int_{E}g\cdot f,\text{ for all } f \text{ in } L^p(E).\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> Then for each bounded linear functional $F$ on $L^p(E)$, there is a unique function $g\in L^q(E)$
> for which $T_g=F$ and $||F|| = ||g||_q$.

*Note:* The norm on $F$, i.e. $||F||$, it given by,
\begin{align*}
||F||:= \sup\left\{\frac{|F|}{||f||_p}: f\in L^p(E)\right\}.
\end{align*}

---

I am trying to understand what this theorem is saying, but I don't know if I'm interpreting it correctly. That is, I *believe* it's saying that *every* bounded linear functional on $L^p(E)$ is of the form $(1)$, for a unique $g$ in $L^q(E)$. Is this correct? Also, could someone give an explicit example of a bounded linear function $F$ on on $L^p(E)$ and show that, in fact, it equals $(1)$?

Comment: "Is this correct?" Yes! For the counting measure, show that $F : (a_n)\to a_1$ is of the form $F((a_n)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$.